# Form a variable from a string without dictionary

Tags: python, django

This is sort of a duplicate, maybe, but I haven't found a solution that fits my needs.

I have a function which builds django-tables2.  I pass in a parameter of a model_class as a string.  Right now that can be 'application', 'database', or 'item', but there will eventually be many more.  In order to configure the table, I set:

`table = DatabaseTable(assets)`

I would like to be able to pass in the model_class so that the table is dynamic based on the type of input it's getting.  Something like:

`table = model_class + Table(assets)` (pseudo)

I don't want to hardcode the dictionary as I'm not sure how many values will eventually be added.  I see people suggesting using `exec`, but those suggestions are all followed by other users threatening to murder those people's families.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been asked many times on stack and the answer is always the same:  when you want an association between names and objects, the one obvious way to do it is with a dictionary.

> I don't want to hardcode the dictionary as I'm not sure how many
>   values will eventually be added.

So you want to avoid a situation like this

```
lookup = {'application': ApplicationTable, 
          'database': DatabaseTable, 
          'item': ItemTable}
```

Because you don't want to have to maintain the lookup, right?  That's fine, but it is not necessary to hardcode a dictionary like this in order to dynamically retrieve the objects.

If your `eval` is working as you've said it is above, then these names in scope like `ApplicationTable`, `Itemtable` etc must be coming from *somewhere*.  Since I don't know where they are being defined and where new ones are going to appear, I will assume they are being imported from some module called `MyTables`

```
from MyTables import ApplicationTable, Itemtable, BlahTable ...
```

The trick here is to use the `dict` (read: namespace) from the module itself.

```
import MyTables
my_string = 'item'
table = getattr(MyTables, my_string.capitalize() + 'Table')
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this allowed?  It works.

```
table = eval(model_name.capitalize() + 'Table(assets)')
RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
```

Comment: Can the downvoter explain why?  Seems kinda unhelpful to downvote something when I'm straight-up asking if it's acceptable.

Comment: Perhaps consider the downvote as a straight-up opinion that it's not acceptable?

Comment: Possibly, but since I came looking for information on that topic, it's not very helpful to me or future readers, especially when it's the only answer on the page.  I'm eager to hear better answers and/or reasons why this one is not good.  On top of that, with zero explanation, I have no idea whether the down-voter has a good point or just likes clicking triangles.

Comment: Althought it's a potential reason to kill the coder in the future, this answer respected the preconditions of the question.

Comment: Both the question and the answer belonged to me, so take it with a grain of salt.  The accepted answer worked well, but I'd love if anyone could elaborate on why this is a bad idea.  Or on what the potential uses of exec and eval are, since they seem universally reviled.